# How to kick off the change event in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want a user to be able to type in a text box which autocompletes, but if its not found I want it to submit the text of what has been written rather than the value (in this case the projectId).

My current thought is to capture the change event (look at the commented out code) and then update the hidden field which will be passed to an ASP.NET MVC controller through model binding.

My javascript looks like this:

```
    $(function () {

        $('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
        .each(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url"),
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).next('input:hidden').val(ui.item.value);
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).next('input:hidden').val(ui.item.value);
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    alert(ui.item.value);

                    //if (ui.item.value == null) {
                    //    $(this).next('input:hidden').val(ui.item.label);
                    //}
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<label for="ProjectID">Project</label>
<input type='text' data-autocomplete-url='/Projects/GetProjectsByUser' />\
<input id="ProjectID" name="ProjectID" type="hidden" value="" />
```

The change event is **not** firing - any idea why?

Comment: Because everytime a keystroke is there - there is a change?

Comment: what will happen if you put a name attribute on the input box ?

Comment: Sorry Andreas, I meant is NOT firing.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several problems with this.

1. [**change**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change) event is triggered when the field is blurred, if the value has changed, not on key press.
2. It seems there is a problem with selector, if you add class or id to your input, it works.
3. **ui.item** in alert reported null, so ui.item.value would not fire alert box at all. Instead I put **$(this).val()** and finally it returns inserted text.

Here is my slightly changed code:

```
<label for="ProjectID">Project</label>
<input class.='ac' type='text' data-autocomplete-url='/Projects/GetProjectsByUser' />
<input id="ProjectID" name="ProjectID" type="hidden" value="" /> 

$(function () {       
    $('.ac').each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url"),
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert('se');
                $(this).next('input:hidden').val(ui.item.value);
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                alert('f');
                $(this).next('input:hidden').val(ui.item.value);
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
});
```